# Mongo select conversations based on messages

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document for a message:

```
{ sender: ObjectId, receiver: ObjectId, message: string, createdAt: Date }
```

where sender and receiver refer to User.

The problem is selecting unique ids of the users with who provided user had at least one common message.
Something like this, but only distinct ids:

```
async getConversations(id) {
return this.personalMessageModel.find({
    $or: [
      { sender: Types.ObjectId(id) },
      { receiver: Types.ObjectId(id) },
    ],
  })
  .sort({ createdAt: 'asc' })
```

}